# How to transform in Java a Twitter Timestamp into a Date

Tags: java, twitter, timestamp

I need to transform a Twitter timestampe into a Java Date object,
here is an example of a value of a Timestampe: "2015-01-06T21:07:00Z"

Can you please give me sample of java code (standard Java) doing the job?

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and try to format the date to match that output.

Comment: @clinomaniac The `SimpleDateFormat` class was supplanted by the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class years ago. All the troublesome old legacy date-time classes are made obsolete by the *java.time* classes.

Comment: Search Stack Overflow before posting a Question. All the basic date-time issues have been asked and answered.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you take advantage of the new Date/Time API introduced in Java 8, specifically `Instant` as follows:

```
Instant.parse("2015-01-06T21:07:00Z");
```

You can then perform a multitude of operations, but keep in mind that the object is immutable, so any changes to the instance (that aren't chained) must be stored in a separate variable.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is ISO 8601 format for UTC time zone.

It conforms with XML DateTime format as well.
So, to get actual `java.util.Calendar` or `java.util.Date` out of it you simply can use available in JDK

```
Calendar twitterCalendar = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime("2015-01-06T21:07:00Z");
Date twitterDate = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime("2015-01-06T21:07:00Z").getTime();
```

Just be aware: `java.util.Date` has no Time Zone information in it. Your string is in UTC, so if you try to print value of twitterDate you will see Date/Time in TimeZone of your computer/server.  Still actual value of twitterDate stays the same

> millisecond value that is an offset from the Epoch, January 1, 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT (Gregorian).